# While trying to Restore record into salesforce from Recyclebin

Tags: apex, trigger, recycle-bin

While trying to insert record into database from recycle bin:

For ex, I have contact record in my salesforce and i have deleted that contact record, that stored in recycle bin.

After deleting the contact record, i have created new record in contact object (as it is deleted contact record has information like, first name, last name, email previously deleted record from contact).

I have written a trigger for contact object, that is while inserting new contact fire error, if first name, last name, email is there.

my question is.... Can i restore the contact record from recycle bin already existing same details in contact object?

In that time, trigger will fire or not?

How can I write trigger to restore records from the recycle bin?

Which context variable can I have to use?

Answer (score 2):

This [Triggers documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) explains that:

> A trigger is Apex code that executes before or after the following
>   types of operations:
>   
>   insert
>   update
>   delete
>   merge
>   upsert
>   **undelete**
>   
>   For
>   example, you can have a trigger run before an object's records are
>   inserted into the database, after records have been deleted, or even
>   **after a record is restored from the Recycle Bin**.

So you can write a trigger that performs custom logic for an object type when it is restored from the Recycle Bin by handling the **after undelete** trigger event. Think through your current Contact trigger and work out how to incorporate the new **after undelete** logic to achieve what you want.

Comment: After restoring records from undelete does the record have new id or the old one?